# Por que alguns package do npm possui um '@' precedendo no nome da conta e outros não, na lista de deps do package-json?

Tags: javascript, npm, packages, yarn

Um exemplo seria o package `@brazilian-utils/brazilian-utils` e `luxon`, eu já suspeitei sobre uns serem privados e outro públicos mas o brazilian-utils mata essa suspeita. O que diferencia o package para ele ter um '@' precedendo o nome do repositório?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é uma feature da NPM que permite *namespaces* nas bibliotecas. No trabalho temos cerca de 6 bibliotecas nossas que carregamos em diversos projetos. Para além de ser prático ver de onde vem permite também evitar limites nos nomes uma vez que permite bibliotecas com o mesmo nome mas em *namespaces* diferentes.

O Lodash por exemplo exporta a biblioteca de maneira a ser possível consumir `@lodash/debounce` como um nome num `import debounce from '@lodash/debounce'`, assim com *namespace*  é mais fácil de organizar bibliotecas e seus sub-componentes.

Comment: Ai neste caso o namespace sempre precisa ter o `@`?
Depois que postei isso achei isso na [doc do npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):
`npm install [<@scope>/]<name>`